# Title of second y-axis in stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a graph with two y axes (below code), but the title of the right-side y-axis does not appear. Can anyone please help me with that?

```
sysuse auto, clear

generate kpl=mpg*0.425144 

twoway (scatter mpg weight, color(navy) yaxis(1)) (scatter kpl weight, color(navy) yaxis(2) ylabel(4.25 8.5 12.75 17, axis(2)) ytitle(Kilometres per Litre, axis(2))),  by(foreign, legend(off) note(Graphs by Car origin))
```

[image: graph]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJfiX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want but I would approach it quite differently.

If you want a second scale of km per litre to compare with miles per gallon, that is just the same data points explained differently, just as you could show Celsius and Fahrenheit temperatures on different axes or calculate proportions and show percents, or vice versa.

Another variable holding km per litre makes this more difficult, not easier, as the values differ by the corresponding conversion factor.

Here I use `mylabels` from SSC, which must be installed before you can use it.

Naturally you don't need to show zero, but the identity 0 miles per gallon = 0 km per litre may make the point easier to follow.

```
sysuse auto, clear

set scheme s1color 

mylabels 0(4)16, myscale(@/0.425144) local(yla)

scatter mpg weight, yaxis(1 2) yla(`yla', axis(2) ang(h)) yla(0(10)40, axis(1) ang(h)) ytitle(km per litre, axis(2)) ms(Oh)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Nick for answering my question and apology for any inconvenience due to my incomplete code. Actually, this is my class assignment to recreate a graph using generate function. The provided plot is exactly the same as what my code gives except the y-axis title that I couldn't fix.

Comment: That's probably a side-effect of working with `by()`. `r1title(Kilometres per Litre)` should work. The graphs aren't exactly the same as your labels for km per litre are multiples of 4.25.

Comment: Thanks Nick, finally solved. The "r1title" worked. Thanks for your time.